# Concat and minify CSS files with Webpack without require them

Tags: gulp, bundle, webpack

I've got and old part of an application that contains some CSS files that are concatenated and minified with gulp script.

And I've got a new application that bundled with Webpack.

Is it possible to assemble the old CSS with Webpack without any additional require calls? Just get all CSS from old_css/**/*.css, concat, minify and write to assets/old.css?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this by "requiring" the CSS files through a separate [entry](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry). You'll end up with something like this:

```
{
    entry: {
        styles: glob('old_css/**/*.css'), // array of css files
        ...
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
        ...
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[chunkhash].css'),
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```

You'll end up with a JavaScript file named after your style entry in addition to the CSS file. You can ignore that, though.